Indexing from a 3D numpy array using another 3D numpy array
I have a 3D array, say a. I want to create another array b which has 0s at least and second least absolute values in a. My approach is as follows
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(100, 4, 4)
c = np.argsort(np.abs(a), axis=2)[..., :2]
b = np.ones(a.shape)

# I need to do b[c] = 0

However the code b[c] = 0 does not work. Also c has entries from 0 to 3 only, therefore the indices for first and second dimension in b need to be inferred from the location of the index in c. How does one go about it? Any help is appreciated.

Assuming unique values you could sort and compare the array to the nth (2nd) column:
N = 2 # second item

a_abs = np.abs(a)
c = np.where(a_abs <= np.sort(a_abs, axis=2)[:, :, [N-1]], 0, 1)

Example:
np.random.seed(0)
shape = 2, 3, 4
P = np.prod(shape)
a = np.random.choice(P, P, replace=False).reshape(shape)-N//2

# array([[[ -1,  -2,  10,   2],
#         [  8, -11,   1,  11],
#         [  4,  -4,  -6,   5]],

#        [[ -8, -10,  -7,   6],
#         [ -3,  -5,   7,  -9],
#         [-12,   9,   3,   0]]])

a_abs = np.abs(a)
c = np.where(a_abs <= np.sort(a_abs, axis=2)[:, :, [1]], 0, 1)

# array([[[0, 0, 1, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 1, 1]],

#        [[1, 1, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1, 1],
#         [1, 1, 0, 0]]])

If your values are not necessarily unique and you want to flag exactly 2, you could pre-process with scipy.stats.rankdata:
from scipy.stats import rankdata

N = 2

rank = rankdata(np.abs(a), axis=2, method='ordinal')
c = np.where(rank <= 2, 0, 1)

